# why I produces 65536 messages to kafka but only got hundreds consumed?

Tags: apache-kafka, producer

kafka version: 1.0.0
sarama version: 1.15.0
go version: 1.9.1

the code sample like this:

```
func main() {
    config := sarama.NewConfig()
    config.Version = sarama.V1_0_0_0
    config.Producer.Return.Successes = true
    config.Producer.RequiredAcks = sarama.WaitForAll
    // config.Producer.Flush.Frequency = 10 * time.Second
    // config.Producer.Flush.Bytes = 1024 * 1024
    // config.Producer.Flush.MaxMessages = 1024
    producer, err := sarama.NewAsyncProducer(strings.Split(*brokers, ","), config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Trap SIGINT to trigger a graceful shutdown.
    signals := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(signals, os.Interrupt)

    var (
        wg                          sync.WaitGroup
        enqueued, successes, errors int
    )

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for range producer.Successes() {
            successes++
        }
    }()

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for err := range producer.Errors() {
            log.Println(err)
            errors++
        }
    }()
    counter := 0

ProducerLoop:
    for {
        if counter >= 65536 {
            producer.AsyncClose() // Trigger a shutdown of the producer.
            break ProducerLoop
        }
        message := &sarama.ProducerMessage{
            Topic: *topics,
            // Key:       sarama.StringEncoder(fmt.Sprintf("%d", counter)),
            // Partition: int32(counter),
            Value: sarama.StringEncoder(fmt.Sprintf("%d,%d", counter, time.Now().UnixNano())),
            // Timestamp: time.Now(),
        }
        select {
        case producer.Input() <- message:
            enqueued++

        case <-signals:
            producer.AsyncClose() // Trigger a shutdown of the producer.
            break ProducerLoop
        }
        if *verbose {
            fmt.Printf(".")
        }
        if *sleep {
            // fmt.Println(100 * time.Millisecond)
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Millisecond)
        }
        counter++
    }

    wg.Wait()

    log.Printf("Successfully produced: %d; errors: %d\n", successes, errors)
}
```

from the log I found 65536 messages sent to kafka, but when I consumed using the kafka official consumer client, only got hundred messages, I am quite confused

I used the official consumer tool to do this:

```
$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server $KAFKA_BROKERS --topic fire-8  --from-beginning
```

as to offsets and partitions when produced, I logged them too. It's too long to paste here. The count matches , I didn't find anything weird

any explanations are appreciated.

I posted an [issue](https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/issues/1034) on GitHub also.

update 1

I found if I set sleep, the gap between consumed and produced was reduced.

update 2

I found the data I send in log, but I cannot consume, something with consumer got wrong I guess

#### update3

I replay the steps above on older kafka cluster (0.10.1.0), everything works exactly as expected

Comment: Try logging both the message count and the offsets committed also , that way you be sure that those many messages are committed to kafka , so you can be sure if it producer or consumer issue

Comment: Nullne, could you update your question with consumer code/command/configuration please? I would like to make sure the problem is not in consuming.

Comment: @DanielWojda I used the official consumer tool and I updated above

Comment: @LijuJohn thank you and I logged the offset and partition and updated above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be the bug of the kafka go client: sarama. I found the solution from the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/issues/1034#issuecomment-363407191) I posted: remove the kafka version config and it works. But this lost some new features brought by new version. If you didn't specify the version you are used, the oldest is the default